# PHP Mysql, cannot get right results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join together two tables, but I cannot get the results I want to get.

So the results I'm looking for is that, I want to be able to "echo" out all the Topic where a user has been involved, by either creating the topic och making a post/comment inside the topic.

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Topics 
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Topics.topic_creator = 'AAAA' 
                OR Posts.Post_creator = 'AAAA'
```

But with this sql I don't really get the result, it's giving me multiple sample of same `Topic_id` and sometimes it just prints out all topics/posts.

So the tables I'm working with is:

Table 1 - Topics:

[image: topics - table]

Table 2 - Posts

[image: posts - table]

I would be grateful if someone more experienced would like to help me solve this PHP problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post those images as text in the question. Images tend to disappear where the question does not. That makes the question useless to other with similiar issues, and thats the basic premise of SO

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables with the column page_id so you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Topics 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Topics.Page_id = Posts.Page_id 
WHERE Posts.Post_creator = 'the_name';
```

It's just an example, I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Topics 
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Topics.Page_id = Posts.Page_id 
where Topics.topic_creator = 'AAAA' OR Posts.Post_creator = 'AAAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically not a php problem but rather an sql problem. Your SQL Join should look something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Topics 
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Topics.id = Posts.Topic_id 
WHERE Topics.Topic_creator = 'AAA'
```

Comment: This will only return the topics that the user has created, not the ones they've posted in.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a `UNION`. One query returns all the topics that the user created, the other returns all the topics that the user posted in.

```
SELECT *
FROM Topics
WHERE Creator = 'AAA'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM Topics AS t
JOIN Posts AS p ON p.Topic_id = t.id
WHERE t.Creator != 'AAA'
AND p.Post_creator = 'AAA'
```

Also, notice that the second query only selects `t.*`, since you just want topic information, not information about all his posts. And `DISTINCT` prevents it from returning a row for each of his posts in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
select * from Topics t
join Posts p
on t.id = p.Topic_id
where t.Topic_creator = 'AAA'
or p.Post_creator = 'AAA'
```

Make sure you have indexes on t.id, p.Topic_id, t.Topic_creator and p.Post_creator

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM Topics t LEFT JOIN Posts p ON t.topic_creator = p.Post_creator
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. It's not returning anything related to the user `AAA` that he's looking for.

Comment: This will return a row for all topics (because it's a `LEFT JOIN`), and also all posts that were written by the topic creator.